# MySQL: mass delete of rows with their relations with individual rollback

Tags: mysql, csv, sql-delete, dump, rollback

I am looking for the best way to perform a mass delete of MySQL rows while being able to rollback them individually later if needed.

**Use Case 1:**

- **Input:** a CSV file with a list of ids of a table
- **Goal:** delete the rows with the given ids from the table and all their relations in the other tables of the database. Generate a script (per id?) so the data can be rolled-back individually on demand later. There is no foreign constraints so the order doesn't matter.

**Use Case 2:**

- **Input:** a CSV file with a list of ids of a table (same table as use case 1)
- **Goal:** use the scripts generated in use case 1 to rollback all the data (relation tables as well) given by the ids in the CSV file.

**Volumetry:** about 10k identifiers per CSV, 1 table with 5 direct relations and 5 indirect ones (1 table in between)

**My questions are:**

- How and what would be the easiest/better way to perform these actions? SQL dumps/queries? Shell script to generate them? PHP script? Other?
- Today I already have PHP scripts that run on a server with a copy of the database to perform other actions (exports) so it doesn't interfer with the production database. Would it be a good practice to run the script that generates the SQL delete and rollback scripts on this server as well. They would then be launched on the production at night? Or is 10k okay so it doesn't interfer with production too much?
- How to generate individual rollback scripts so they can be run in mass later if needed (use case 2)? use of mysqldump? merging the scripts into one depending on what's in the CSV?

Thank you for your help and advice on this.

Regards,

Comment: I would take a different approach and log all the deleted entries someplace and restore from there if need be.

Comment: First, thank you for your reply. Okay yeah, but how would you store them (sql files? other?) and what would you use to execute the rollback procedure? I'd need a bit more precision. Thank your for your help.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you delete rows at all if you plan to activate them again. You could just add a column `deleted` to your table and ignore these rows in your app (or have a base table that just contains the active ids and join with this table).

Comment: That would be an interesting idea if I could change the app, but I have the constraint not to, it would just take too much time. The rollback procedure would be in case some of the ids didn't have to be in the 10k lines CSV file in the first place. Considering the first case only for now, what would be the best way of scripting this according to you? Use a shell script that read the CSV and make all to requests to get all the ids from the tables and generate a single SQL file or use PHP or anyother language? Thank you